# Sending two servlet responses per request

Tags: java, http, servlets

I write, because I can not solve the following problem.
I have a servlet that processes some information.
In response I put both text and binary content.
How do I get two response, then two html page, starting from the same request?
is a thing possible?
The first response should continue to do what he does now, while the second would appear to make a popup window to save an image.
There are easier ways to achieve the same result?
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

As answered in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966162/servlet-send-image-from-server-and-save-in-client), You can send only one HTTP response per HTTP request. This is not a servlet restriction, this is a [HTTP](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) restriction. The server is not supposed to send data to the client unaskingly. That would have made the Internet extremely annoying and unusable. As if you're thrown dead with a continuous stream of spam.

To be able to return two responses, the client has to fire two requests **itself**. If you want to do this automagically on a "single click", then you can (ab)use some shot of JavaScript for this. E.g.

```
<a href="page.jsp" onclick="window.open('downloadservlet/file.ext')">click</a>
```

This will fire two requests, one to `page.jsp` using normal HTML in current window and another one to `downloadservlet/file.ext` in new window using JavaScript. This window will however disappear if the response is of `Content-Disposition: attachment` as answered in your previous question.

You only need to take into account that this won't work when the client has JavaScript *disabled*.

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct! Most HTTP interactions are purely request-response, however the response code [102 Processing](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2518#section-10.1) calls for multiple responses on the same stream. 

There are use-cases for this response, however most framewords don't seem to take these into account.

Comment: @penguineer: Ha! Moreover, things have changed since HTTP/2.